# Transitions GraphMachine produces fully connected graph

Tags: python, transition

Using [transitions](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions), when I create a GraphMachine and then call `graph.draw` on the machine, the resultant graph is fully connected, even though I only have a few transitions defined. How do I get a graph with only defined transitions?

Answer (score 2):

Aaaaaand the answer is in the docs:

**Automatic transitions for all states**

In addition to any transitions added explicitly, a to_«state»() method is created automatically whenever a state is added to a Machine instance. This method transitions to the target state no matter which state the machine is currently in:

```
lump.to_liquid()
lump.state
>>> 'liquid'
lump.to_solid()
lump.state
>>> 'solid'
```

If you desire, you can disable this behavior by setting auto_transitions=False in the Machine initializer.

and sure'nuff, that gave me the result I want.

I thought I'd answer my own question in case someone else had the same problem. If that's bad form, I'll remove it.

Cheers